# loopback foreign key validation

Tags: loopbackjs

I´m trying to validate foreignKey in my model when I POST new record.
My relation has "options": {"validate": true, "forceId": false}.

But when I POST new object, returns OK when the new record inserted and an inválid ID of a relation object.

```
{
  "name": "Neighborhood",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "country": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Country",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
    },
    "employees": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Employee",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [        
  ],
  "methods": {}
}

{
  "name": "Employee",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "rol": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "birthDate": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "neighborhood": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Neighborhood",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "options": {        
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `validate` option only works for embedded relationships.

Comment: Ok. So I should implement manually. Do you have an example with "before save" action or similar? Thanks.

Comment: Any help?. I tried with embedded relationship but not work for me. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I don't think those options do anything in the way you are using them, they are only for embedded relationships. Instead, you might need to use a `before save` operation hook:

```
Neighborhood.observe('before save', function verifyForeignKeys(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) { // for single model update
    // check ctx.instance.fkField
    if (theKeyisNotValid) {
      return next(new Error('Bad foreign key...'));
    }
  } else { // for multi-model update
    // check ctx.data.fkField
  }
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jakerella , It´s works. Here is the complete sample:

```
module.exports = function (Neighborhood) {

    Neighborhood.observe('before save', function verifyForeignKeys(ctx, next) {
        if (ctx.instance) { // for single model update
            // check ctx.instance.fkField
            var s = ctx.instance;
            var countryId = s.__data.countryId;            

            //Get the Application object which the model attached to, and we do what ever we want
            Neighborhood.getApp(function (err, app) {
                //App object returned in the callback
                //PersistedModel.exists(id, callback ((err, exists)))
                app.models.Country.exists(countryId, function (err, exists) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (!exists)
                        return next(new Error('Bad foreign key...'));
                });
            });
            next();
        }});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is:

```
Neighborhood.validateAsync('countryId', hasCountryId, {
    code: 'notFound.relatedInstance',
    message: 'related instance not found'
});


function hasCountryId(err, next) {
    // Use the next if countryId is not required
    if (!this.countryId) {
        return next();
    }

    var Country = Neighborhood.app.models.Country;

    Country.exists(this.countryId, function (error, instance) {
        if (error || !instance) {
            err();
        }
        next();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is possible by creating and using mixins (sorry for the comments in French)

/common/mixins/BelongsToIntegrityCheck.js

```
'use strict'

let _ = require('lodash');

let checkBelongsToIntegrity = function (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    let relations = ctx.Model.definition.settings.relations;
    let relationsArray = _.map(relations, rel => {
      return { modelName: rel.model, fk: rel.foreignKey, type: rel.type };
    });

    /* On utilise Lodash pour transformer l'objet des relations en Tableau de la forme
      [
        { modelName: 'achat', fk: 'achat_id', type: 'belongsTo' },
        { modelName: 'FED_AGENT', fk: 'agent_rfagent', type: 'belongsTo' }
      ]
    */

    let thisModel = ctx.Model;
    // Le message qui sera renvoyé en cas d'échec de vérification des contraintes d'intégrité
    let message = "";
    // Le tableau des promises correspondant aux requêtes vérifiants les contraintes
    let promiseArray = [];

    relationsArray.forEach(function (relation) {
      if (relation.type == 'belongsTo') {
        let parentModelName = relation.modelName;
        let parentModel = thisModel.app.models[parentModelName];
        let parentId = ctx.instance[relation.fk];

        // On cherche le modèle parent qui correspond à l'id demandé pour le modèle enfant...
        promiseArray.push(parentModel.findById(parentId).then(function (parentInstance) {
          if (parentInstance === null) {
            message += 'No ' + parentModelName + ' with "' + parentId + '" id. ';
          }
        }));

      }
    }
    );

    /* Une fois que toutes les promesses ont été déterminées et conduisent vers un message en cas de non respect de la contrainte d'intégrité,
    on les regroupe dans une promesse commune résolue quand toutes sont résolues et qui renvoit le message en cas de non respect de contrainte */
    Promise.all(promiseArray)
      .then(
      function () {
        next(message);
      }
      , console.error)
      .catch(function (err) {
        next(err);
      });
  }
}

module.exports = function (Model, options) {
  Model.observe('before save', checkBelongsToIntegrity);
};
```

/common/mixins/HasManyIntegrityCheck.js

```
'use strict'

let _ = require('lodash');

let checkHasManyIntegrity = function (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.where) {
    let relations = ctx.Model.definition.settings.relations;
    let relationsArray = _.map(relations, rel => {
      return { modelName: rel.model, fk: rel.foreignKey, type: rel.type };
    });

    /* On utilise Lodash pour transformer l'objet des relations en Tableau de la forme
      [
        { modelName: 'achat', fk: 'achat_id', type: 'belongsTo' },
        { modelName: 'FED_AGENT', fk: 'agent_rfagent', type: 'belongsTo' }
      ]
    */

    let thisModel = ctx.Model;
    // Le message qui sera renvoyé en cas d'échec de vérification des contraintes d'intégrité
    let message = "";
    // Le tableau des promises correspondant aux requêtes vérifiants les contraintes
    let promiseArray = [];

    relationsArray.forEach(function (relation) {
      if (relation.type == 'hasMany') {
        let childrenModelName = relation.modelName;
        let childrenModel = thisModel.app.models[childrenModelName];
        let parentId = ctx.where.id;
        let whereObject = {};
        whereObject[relation.fk] = ctx.where.id;
        // On cherche les enfants éventuels
        promiseArray.push(childrenModel.find({
          where: whereObject
        }).then(function (data) {
          if (data.length > 0) { // Si il y a des enfants, on renvoit une erreur
            message += 'This "' + thisModel.modelName + '" has "' + childrenModelName + '", and can\'t be deleted. ';
          }
        }));

      }
    }
    );

    /* Une fois que toutes les promesses ont été déterminées et conduisent vers un message en cas de non respect de la contrainte d'intégrité,
    on les regroupe dans une promesse commune résolue quand toutes sont résolues et qui renvoit le message en cas de non respect de contrainte */
    Promise.all(promiseArray)
      .then(
      function () {
        next(message);
      }
      , console.error)
      .catch(function (err) {
        next(err);
      });
  }
}

module.exports = function (Model, options) {
  Model.observe('before delete', checkHasManyIntegrity);
};
```

And in your models :

Parent Model :

```
"mixins": {
  "HasManyIntegrityCheck": {}
},
```

Children Model :

```
"mixins": {
  "BelongsToIntegrityCheck": {}
},
```